# finding value of g(2) using integration

Tags: integration

Let g:$[0,\infty) \to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous function satisfying $\int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt=x  , for all x\in[0,\infty)$. Then g(2) is equal to ?

given : $\int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt=x $ differentiating both sides with respect to x

$\frac{d}{dx}$$\int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt=1 $  .  Let $\int g(x)dt=G(x)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{d}{dx}$[G($x^2(1+x))-G(0)$]=1

$\Rightarrow$$[g(x^2(1+x)$) (2x(1+x)+x^2)] - 0  =1

put x=1 $\Rightarrow$ g(2)=1/5

please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Nah, you're exactly right.

Comment: The only error is in the title because you actually find $g(2)$ using differentiation, not integration ;)